# OSGi NoClassDefFoundError on Apache ServiceMix 5.4.0

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to deploy my osgi bundles(which are work nice on Geronimo 3.0.1) to ServiceMix.
Bundle A exports com.mycompany.api package, bundle B imports it. 
But i'm getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.api.Version
```

It happens when i call static method getMajor() from com.mycompany.api.Version class in bundle B. Other classes from api package work fine, even with other static methods/fields.
**Version.java:**

```
public class Version {
  private static int VERSION_MAJOR = 0;
  private static int VERSION_MINOR = 0;
  private static int VERSION_BUILD = 0;

  static{
      String v = Version.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
      String av[] = v.split("\\.");
      VERSION_MAJOR = Integer.parseInt(av[0]);
      VERSION_MINOR = Integer.parseInt(av[1]);
      VERSION_BUILD = Integer.parseInt(av[2]);
  }

  public static int getMajor(){
      return VERSION_MAJOR;
  }

  public static int getMinor(){
      return VERSION_MINOR;
  }

  public static int getBuild(){
      return VERSION_BUILD;
  }
}
```

### upd

full stack trace:

```
2015-07-29 07:57:31,884 | ERROR | qtp882005584-238 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 18 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.2 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.mycompany.bundleB
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean Intializer
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:714)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:526)[213:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.console:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:450)[213:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.console:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.KarafOsgiManager.doService(KarafOsgiManager.java:74)[213:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.console:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.KarafOsgiManager$1.run(KarafOsgiManager.java:54)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:67)[20:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:2.4.1]
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.KarafOsgiManager.service(KarafOsgiManager.java:52)[213:org.apache.karaf.webconsole.console:2.4.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:77)[73:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[64:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycompany.api.Version
    at com.mycompany.server.Version.checkAPIVersion(Version.java:69)
    at com.mycompany.Initializer.checkVersion(Initializer.java:53)
    at com.mycompany.Initializer.init(Initializer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:958)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)
    ... 61 more
```

line 69 of com.mycompany.server.Version

```
if (com.mycompany.api.Version.getMajor() < API_VERSION_MAJOR){
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, not just the first line.

Comment: Can you post the Manifests of both bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in

```
Version.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

it was null, so

```
String av[] = v.split("\\.");
```

causes nullpointer exception, which wasn't logged for some reason.

I didnt mentioned before, but my bundle is actually a wrapper around api.jar, it have the following structure:

```
api-osgi.jar
  --META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  --WEB-INF/lib/api.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

"Implementation-Version" was only inside api.jar's manifest, and it was ok for Geronimo.
Adding it to manifest of the OSGi bundle, fixed the problem for Service mix.

Thank you guys for your intention to help.